# How to make a custom column's value in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, url, select, alias

for exam I have 2 table

```
1) Post - and its columns :
pid :
uid :
title :
content :
created date :
```

...

```
2) URL alias
aid :
sou_url :
des_url :
```

The second table used to store url-alias for all pages in my site
I created an function to get alias like this

```
function get_alias_url($surl);

for exam get_alias_url("pid/50") = "this-is-my-first-post";
```

So now, I want to select all posts that has url alias's length > 50
I wondering,is there any way to make a query to do that?
It may be look like :

```
Select * from post where length(get_alias_url("pid/nid")) > 50
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in bytes. 
`CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in characters.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE char_length('. get_alias_url("pid/nid").' ) > 50';
```

Your PHP function should still work inside your query.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL CHAR_LENGTH() function in your query.

For a full list of functions related to strings in MySQL, go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: Thank for your reply, but my question is : Can I use php function in mysql like that?

Comment: You could use it in your query string itself, like when you're building it to send to your prepared statement. Could you maybe explain your intentions a little more clearly? I can adjust my answer.;

Comment: Awesome! glad it helped you at least somewhat